# Hibernate Query by Example(QBE) Check All Fields Empty for Security

Tags: java, hibernate

As I know Hibernate can query by example like this:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.setName("CAT1");
Example example = Example.create(cat);
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class).add(example);
criteria.list();
```

When don't set the name to cat, the code will fetch all the cats in table. This may cause problem if the table is large.
Is there one simple official method to check if all the fields are empty before the query execute(I think reflection is not official)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the QBE should at DAO layer and the restriction of check all fields empty is not valid. We should check logic empty at service layer.